# A dimension of graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I have searched definitions of the dimension of a graph but I haven't  found what I'm looking for. Has anyone considered the minimal dimension of the ambient space for the geometric representation of a graph, assuming straight, nonintersecting edges? Pointing to any literature would be great.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the graph, the dimension is either $0,1,2\ $ or $3$.

Dimension $0$: the one-point graph $K_1$.

Dimension $1$: path-forests (each component is a path).

Dimension $2$: planar graphs (no subgraph homeomorphic to $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$). The fact that every planar graph has a straight-line drawing in the plane is [Fary's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry%27s_theorem).

Dimension $3$: all graphs; place the vertices on the twisted cubic $x=t,y=t^2,z=t^3$ and join them up with straight line segments.

**Update.** Oh, I thought you were asking about **finite** graphs. Dimension $3$ works for all (simple!) graphs with at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ vertices; just map the vertices to distinct points on that curve and join them up with straight line segments, they won't cross. Dimension $2$ works for **countable** graphs, but for instance the disjoint union of $\aleph_1$ copies of $K_{1,3}$ can not be drawn in the plane without crossings, even if you don't require the edges to be straight line segments.

Comment: Got me by a second. @JacobWakem: you see that there is a great gap between dimension 2 and 3. To refine this gap, it is common to look at the minimum genus of a surface on which a graph can be embedded. For example, $K_4$ is embeddable on the sphere (genus $0$), whereas $K_5$ up to $K_7$ can be embedded on the torus (genus $1$), and $K_8$ can be embedded on the double torus (genus $2$).

Comment: @bof: this probably means I need to spend more time with your D3 argument, but does that extend to countable graphs?

Comment: With no deep exploration of the subject, my intuition says it does not: any respectable nontrvial graph you could imagine on $\Bbb Q^3$ seems unlikely to be 3-dimensional.

Comment: @EricStucky For a countable graph, you can just map the vertices to random points in the unit cube, and join them up with straight lines. With probability one, no four points will be coplanar, so there won't be any crossings.

Comment: @bof: Augh, you're right. I forgot that you get to choose the embedding of the vertices as well as the edges :/